# Structural typing is not duck typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-systems, duck-typing, structural-typing

As mentioned in TypeScript [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type-checking focuses on the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”.In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of naming these types,...

---

My understanding is, the above core principle does not relate to *Duck typing* but [Structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), because TypeScript is static typed language.

As mentioned in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): *It requires that type checking be deferred to runtime, and is implemented by means of dynamic typing or reflection... an object's suitability is determined by the presence of certain methods and properties (with appropriate meaning), rather than the actual type of the object.*

How do I understand the above core principle of TypeScript?

Comment: `This is sometimes called "duck typing"`... I don't see a claim that TypeScript *is* formally a Duck Typing system, per the strict definition, and a quick google search shows this statement to be true. TypeScript doesn't really fit into the wikipedia article because it's not a runtime language at all, it's just a type-checker. However it certainly meets several of the criteria, including the basic duck principal and the fact it compiles to JavaScript, a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @Aaron *type-checking focuses on the shapes that value have*, is something to do with Structural typing but not Duck typing. Because my understanding of its meaning is... *type compatibility and equivalence are determined by the type's actual structure or definition*. Further in the handbook, it says the same...  *It’s worth pointing out that the type-checker does not require that these properties come in any sort of order, only that the properties the interface requires are present and have the required type.*

Comment: I think the definition you're using for duck-typing is not wrong, but not complete in how the term is used, which is why TypeScript is sometimes called "duck typing".

Comment: @Aaron Due to type check in compile-time vs run-time, I see below example like this.. **1)** `let myObj:labelledValue = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"};` has to go for compile-time type check, which follows structural typing. **2)** Parameter object received in `function printLabel(labelledObj: LabelledValue) {..}` can only be checked at runtime, where there is no type(`function printLabel(labelledObj) {}`), so obviously it is the same rules that JS follows(duck typing), in second case.

Comment: Yes, TS is "compile-time duck-typing" if you want to say.

Comment: @Aaron I think the below answer should have `let myObj = {size: 10, label_1: "Size 10 Object"};`. Code still works dues to duck typing.

Answer (score 6):

From [Duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test) and [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and on Wikipedia

> If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck.

This is essentially how TypeScript interfaces work. An object just has to look like the interface rather than explicitly implement it.

Form the page you linked to:

```
interface LabelledValue {
    label: string;
}

function printLabel(labelledObj: LabelledValue) {
    console.log(labelledObj.label);
}

let myObj = {size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object"};
printLabel(myObj);
```

Even though `myObj` doesn't explicitly implement the `LabelledValue` interface it does have the same structure and therefore implicitly implements the interface. This is Duck Typing

**UPDATE** If the `LabelledValue` interface were defined as a class then the above code wouldn't "compile". This is Structural Typing.

**Note** TypeScript has no runtime checking as it is "compiled" down to JavaScript

Comment: **1)** Ducktyping does not require two objects to have same properties(of same type and name). Duck typing does **not deal with type equivalence**.  For an object, If a property(say method) that you call,  exist, then duck typing says you can call that method. **2)** Structural typing(atleast in TypeScript) **deals with type equivalence** of two objects based on both type and names of the members in those two objects

Comment: Interfaces are a little different though. If an object has the same properties and types as defined in the interface then the object would be accepted as implementing the interface even though it isn't explicitly defined as such.

Comment: If `LabelledValue` was a class then that would change things. and `myObj` wouldn't pass the test and TypeScript would error

Comment: That is bad example, I would say, `let myObj:labelledValue={...}` then no more complications and you cannot call `printLabel()` anymore. This is one of the purpose of `interface` keyword, to solve such problems of JS

Comment: In your answer: *therefore implicitly implements the interface* looks incorrect to me.

Comment: True, you would normally explicitly specify the type, but, _that isn't the point of the example._ The example is there to show you how interfaces (and duck typing) work.

Comment: Isn't *explicit typing* & *duck typing*, mutually exclusive? Why language allow such constructs? to support 3rd part JS libraries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170154/discussion-between-phuzi-and-overexchange).

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Duck {
    typing(): void;
}

const porky = {} as Duck;

try {
    porky.typing();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // TypeError: porky.typing is not a function
}

const isDucky = (it: { typing?: () => void }): it is Duck =>
    typeof it.typing === 'function';

const daffy = {
    typing: () => console.log('tappity tap tap')
};

if (isDucky(daffy)) {
    daffy.typing(); // tappity tap tap
}
```

[image: duck typing]